# Reporting trident token or other indications of a user in compatibility mode within Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I have noticed that the number of users reporting to be using Internet Explorer 9 is high (2%) within browser & OS in Google Analytics. Reviewing the user agent it's clear a higher number of these are running Internet Explorer 11 in compatibility Mode. It appears Google Analytics would represent the following user as IE9. However, the Trident value of 7 indicates they are using Internet Explorer 11. [What's my browser example](https://developers.whatismybrowser.com/useragents/parse/)

```
DeviceType
Mozilla/5.0+(compatible;+MSIE+9.0;+Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64;+Trident/7.0;+Touch)
```

I've seen older [threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25312678/google-analytics-reports-a-high-amount-of-internet-explorer-7-traffic/25312679#) stating that it's not possible to report browser by the trident token or if the the user is in compatibility mode.

Is this still the case? Are there other tools within Google Analytics that could give an accurate represent of the IE 9 usage?